# Определить открытые директории в Linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени суток!

Друзья, есть ли возможность в Линукс вывести список всех открытых в системе директорий на данный момент? К примеру, через Caja перехожу в /opt, но с файлами там ничего не делаю. Просто нахожусь в этой директории . Есть ли возможность вывести на экран в консоле, что процесс Caja открыл "/opt"?
Спасибо!

update. Спасибо тем, кто ответил. К сожалению, inotify не подходит, т.к. показывает инфу, если хоть какой - то файл открывали. При чем, если директория не маленькая( home, var и т.д. ) он просто закроется с ошибкой. Проверял в Python. Пока есть "более -менее" готовое решение с парсингом логов auditd( в режиме реального времени ), но простой доступ к директории auditd не показывает. Может, какие еще идеи будут? Спасибо

Comment: Caja не держит папку открытой постоянно, а просто читает список вложенных папок/файлов и быстренько закрывает её, поэтому нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Не обязательно Caja. Все, что угодно: cd в консоле и т.д. К примеру, я хочу знать, какие процессы обращались к /opt в течение часа( даже, если никакие файлы открыты не были, к примеру ), например, вообще. Есть ли возможность как - то это определить? Спасибо.

Comment: но ведь можно переформулировать задачу "как найти все окна менеджеров файлов и получить открытый каталог в них". И это уже более-менее решаемая задача

Comment: а вот если это "а кто обращался", то это другая задача и она решаемая

Comment: @AlexNon это зависит от того, как именно процесс обращается к папке; универсального способа нет.

Comment: Если «в течение часа», то можно попробовать собрать все системные вызовы, связанные с обращением к файловой системе (и не забываем про inotify), перехватывать их, мониторить и анализировать (но я не специалист и не знаю как именно это реализовать)

Comment: KoVadim, andreymal, спасибо. Уточню вопрос: просто есть какая - то директория( например, "/opt"  ). Я хочу узнать, обращался ли к ней какой - нибудь процесс( просто хоть директорию открывали и все ), например, за час. Если да, хочу узнать, какой именно процесс это был и в какое время.

Comment: я ниже написал ответ. Но только он как бы немного "наоборот" - Вам нужно запустить тулу и ждать

Comment: andreymal, с inotify как раз проблема, т.к. он показывает инфу только о хоть как-то затронутых файлах.

Comment: @AlexNon тогда обновите текст вопроса, а то «на данный момент» и «например, за час» это всё-таки сильно разные вещи

Comment: @AlexNon Тогда лучше расскажите, какую именно задачу решаете? антивирус пишете? Мониторингом занимаетесь? Возможно, решается задача XY. Но в любом случае можно попробовать опуститься на уровень ядра.

Comment: Если задача стоит именно как описано, то есть "на данный момент", то почему бы просто не пробежать подкаталоги в /proc, в каждом из них глядя, куда ведёт ссылка cwd?

Comment: Вам нужен audit. Он может логгировать многое.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна программа inotifywait (в убунту-дебиан устанавливается по `apt-get install inotify-tools`).

А дальше где то так

```
inotifywatch -r /opt
```

и готово. А дальше просто попробуйте обратится к каталогу и сразу у себя в консоли все увидите. Возможно, параметр -r Вам и не нужен (он заставляет рекурсивно обрабатывать). Также, эта утилита не безгранична и если каталог большущий, может и отказаться работать.  А дальше к этому можно прицепить баш или любой другой язык программирования.

На почитать

- https://mnorin.com/inotify-v-bash.html

Comment: caja и ls перехватывает, а простой cd игнорирует